# Ubuntu installer crashes on Installation Type screen

Tags: boot, system-installation, lenovo

I am attempting to perform an install of Ubuntu 20.04.1 lTS on my [Lenovo 720 laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/au/en/laptops/yoga/yoga-700-series/Yoga-720-13/p/88YG7000827). I am currently able to live boot from USB, but when I get to the installation type screen in the installer, no options show up, and clicking the plus, minus, or change buttons causes it to crash.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

In order to even live boot Linux I had to change the SATA type from RAID to AHCI. This has made Windows currently unusable, which wasn't going to be a problem since I want to only use Linux.

When I click install now without selecting anything, the dialogue box says "no root file system is defined".

Comment: What method did you use to flash the USB, and can you try another ISO?

Comment: if you did not verify the integrity of your download or your flash, you should try again -- use the bittorrent link to download the ISO and then use balena Etcher to flash the ISO to pen drive.  The BT protocol automatically verifies the integrity of downloads, and Etcher will verify the flash -- it's also nearly impossible to choose the wrong settings in etcher, unlike some other methods of flashing the ISO.